# matlab GPU computation

Tags: matlab, gpu

I am learning matlab GPU functions. My function `myfun` takes 2 input parameters `delta, p`. Eventually, I will apply `myfun` to many combinations of `delta,p`. For each combination of `delta,p`, 'myfun' will how many `V`'s satisfies the condition `delta*V-p>0`, where `V = [0:0.001:1]`. Ideally, I want `V` to be a `global variable`. But it seems that matlab GPU has some restrictions on global variable. So I use another way to do this thing. The code is as the following:

```
 function result = gpueg2()
          dd = 0.1;
          DELTA = [dd:dd:1];
          dp = 0.001;
          P = [0:dp:1];
          [p,delta]=meshgrid(P,DELTA);
          p = gpuArray(p(:));
          delta = gpuArray(delta(:));


           V = [0:0.001:1];

           function [O] = myfun(delta,p)
                     O = sum((delta*V-p)>0);
           end
           result = arrayfun(@myfun,delta,p);
 end
```

However, it through an error message

```
Function passed as first input argument contains unsupported or unknown function 'sum'.
```

But I believe `sum` is applicable in GPU.

Any advice and suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: sum(A) and sum(A>10) have different under the hood implementations. The second, inserts a control flow if, which for a GPU matters a lot. GPUs are very hard to code and only certain functionalities can benefit from their architecture, so when Matlab says it supports sum for GPU arrays, I guess it supports sum(A), sum(A(10:30)) and stuff like that, where the input is an actual array.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `sum` is not with the GPU, it's with using `arrayfun` on a GPU. The list of functions that `arrayfun` on a GPU accepts is given here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/run-element-wise-matlab-code-on-a-gpu.html. `sum` is not on the list on that page of documentation.

Your vectors are not so big (though I accept this may be a toy example of your real problem). I suggest the following alternative implementation:

```
function result = gpueg2()
dd = 0.1;
DELTA = dd:dd:1;
dp = 0.001;
P = 0:dp:1;
V = 0:0.001:1;
[p,delta,v] = meshgrid(P,DELTA,V);
p = gpuArray(p);
delta = gpuArray(delta);
v = gpuArray(v);
result = sum(delta.*v-p>0, 3);
end
```

Note the following differences:

1. I make 3D arrays of `p,delta,v`, rather than 2D. These three are only 24MB in total.
2. I do the calculation `delta.*v-p>0` on the whole 3D array: this will be well split on the GPU.
3. I do the sum on the 3rd index, i.e. over `V`.

I have checked that your routine on the CPU and mine on the GPU give the same results.